# How do I trigger a Jquery function with a Drop down list?

Tags: javascript, .net, jquery, asp.net

I have 2 asp:DropdownLists with an OnSelectedIndexChanged attribute.  When that is triggered I would like to run a jquery function that would let the user know the data is being processed. How do I jump to my jQuery function and is there a way I don't have to use the unique id?

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFirst" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlChange"> 
    <asp:ListItem>All</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>None</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSecond" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlChange"> 
    <asp:ListItem>All</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>None</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

$(document).ready(function () {
$("???").change(function () {
    //code
});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give them a class and use `$('.yourClass')`

Comment: Silly me... I had the class but '#' and not '.' thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have AutoPostBack="true" attribute attached to your DDLs, so I have no idea what are you going to notify your user about. Anyway

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFirst" onchange="myFunc();">
</asp:DropDownList>

function myFunc() {
   // insert JS code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, assign a `CssClass` -

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFirst" CssClass="myDropDown" runat="server" 
              OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlChange"> 
    <asp:ListItem>All</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>None</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSecond" CssClass="myDropDown" runat="server" 
      OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlChange"> 
    <asp:ListItem>All</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>None</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Then, do the following -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".myDropDown").change(function () {
        // code to display user message
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
$("select").change(function () {

});
```

Comment: as ASP.NET dropdowns are just select boxes so I assume this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Give the ddl a class, then do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("select.myClassName").change(function () {
    //code
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey u can use something like this
$(“select[id$='ddlfirst']”)

Answer (score 0):

Using ASP.net there is always this option:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFirst" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlChange"> 
  <asp:ListItem>All</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>None</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#<%= ddlFirst.ClientID %>").change(function () {
    //code
  });
});
```

This will dynamically load the DDL's ID into the javascript that will be loaded onto the page.  I just have my javascript functions on the same page as the asp.net code